# Lambda expression executes correctly but anonymous class definition throws error

Tags: java, functional-interface

I am trying to understand the Consumer interface of Java. I have replicated it. But it throws StackOverflowError when i replace the lambda expression in return statement of andThen() method with anonymous class definition:

```
interface Interface<T> {
       
    void accept(T t);

    default Interface<T> andThen(Interface<T> after) {

           //return (T t)->{accept(t); after.accept(t);};//this runs correctly
           
          //below is the anonymous class definition of above lambda expression
          return new Interface<T>(){

            @Override
            public void accept(T t)
            {
                accept(t); //stackoverflow error thrown
                after.accept(t);
            }
          };
     }
}

//Main class:

public class Lambda2 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Interface<String> e1=str -> System.out.println("in e1 - "+str);
    
        Interface<String> e2=str -> System.out.println("in e2 - "+str);
        
        Interface<String> e3 = e1.andThen(e2);
        
        e3.accept("Sample Output");
    }
}
```

Could you please let me know why the lambda expression of the anonymous class definition does not cause StackOverflowError?

Comment: Because you're not calling `Interface.this.accept`, you're calling the `#accept` of the anonymous class. It may be easiest to keep an `Interface<T> outer = this;` before your anonymous class, then call `outer.accept(t);` inside the anonymous class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the reason for this in [JLS 15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2) (my emphasis):

> Unlike code appearing in anonymous class declarations, **the meaning of names** and the `this` and `super` keywords **appearing in a lambda body**, along with the accessibility of referenced declarations, **are the same as in the surrounding context** (except that lambda parameters introduce new names).

That is, the name `accept` inside the lambda body has the same meaning as the `accept` outside the lambda body; and the difference is an anonymous class is explicitly called out.

So: calling `accept` in a lambda defined the body of the `andThen` method will involve the `accept` method on the instance (just as if you had invoked `accept` directly in the method body); whereas calling `accept` in the body of the `accept` method in the anonymous class will recursively invoke itself.